# Is input valid Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have `textarea` in form:

```
<form name="new_project">
    <textarea autofocus="autofocus"ng-model="description" ng-maxlength="10" name="campaign[description]"></textarea>
</form>
```

I tried to show state of input like:

```
{{new_project.campaign[description].$valid}}
```

It returns nothing, why?

Comment: If you just change the name to ```campaign_description``` for instance it will work.

Comment: I can not change name.

Comment: Then go for  ```{{new_project['campaign[description]'].$valid}} ```

Comment: I've edited my answer, providing an explanation of **why** it was returning nothing. I hope I have been clear enough! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
{{new_project['campaign[description]'].$valid}}
```

**The reason:**

`name="campaign[description]"` adds a property to your form object **named literally as the string** `'campaign[description]'` and the only way to access the value of this property is wrapping that string inside [ ].

**Dot notation here won't work** for you in this particular case because otherwise the JavaScript interpreter would be expecting in `campaign[description]` to access the property of `campaign` provided between the brackets [ ]: in your case the value of `description`, which I guess it would be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form name="new_project">
  <textarea autofocus="autofocus"ng-model="description" ng-maxlength="10"   name="campaign{{description}}"></textarea>
</form>
```

And

```
{{new_project['campaign'+description].$invalid}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `{{new_project.textarea.$valid}}`
pass the element to check the validity